# How to copy from column to row not using PasteSpecial Transpose?

Tags: vba, excel

This loop to copies the values from one sheet's columns to another sheet's columns:

```
Dim ExposureDataInput As Worksheet
Dim ManualSimulation As Worksheet

Set EDI = Sheets("ExposureDataInput")
Set MS = Sheets("ManualSimulation")

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

For i = 2 To EDI.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If EDI.Range("B" & i).Value > 0 Then

       n = MS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       MS.Range("A" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 1).Value

       n = MS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       MS.Range("B" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 2).Value

       n = MS.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       MS.Range("C" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 4).Value

       n = MS.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       MS.Range("D" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 6).Value

       n = MS.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       MS.Range("E" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 8).Value

       n = MS.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       MS.Range("F" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 10).Value

       n = MS.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       MS.Range("G" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 12).Value

   End If

Next i
```

I tried the same principal to get the col A:A from one sheet to a row in another sheet:

```
Dim ExposureDataInput As Worksheet
Dim HistoricalDataandExcessReturns As Worksheet

Set EDI = Sheets("ExposureDataInput")
Set HDaER = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns")

Dim k As Integer
Dim y As Integer

For k = 2 To EDI.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If EDI.Range("B" & k).Value > 0 Then

        y = HDaER.Range(Columns.Count & 1).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        HDaER.Range(y & 1).Value = EDI.Cells(1, k).Value

        y = HDaER.Range(Columns.Count & 2).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        HDaER.Range(y & 2).Value = EDI.Cells(2, k).Value 

   End If

Next k
```

The `i` in the column to column works. When I try with `k` in a column to row it gives me

> Run-time error '1004'.

How can I copy a column to a row?

Comment: Check the value of y, it is probably not what you expect.

Comment: Where did you declare the Sheet in the second Sub? In the first one you did `Set EDI = Sheets("ExposureDataInput")` but I can't see anything similar on the second subroutine...

Comment: @Xabier, I just corrected that.

Comment: You should declare k and y as Long instead of Integer, as there are more cells in Excel than an Integer can handle... The same with i and n..

Comment: @Vincent G, I am trying to copy cells, formated as 'General' that contain text. It works w the col to col, but doesn't w the col to row.

Comment: @Xabier, thank you. I will. Let me see how it will work.

Comment: @Xabier, same error on the same 'k' line - Run-time error '1004'

Comment: Where is this code? Does `For k = 2 To EDI.Range("B" & EDI.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` fix the issue by any chance?

Comment: @ Macro Man, yes, it did, but just for this line. If you see below Xabier's answer, you'll see that now the issue is with the `HDaER.Range(y & 1).Value = EDI.Cells(1, k).Value` line. Same error - '1004'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue lies with the way you are trying to get the last Column, please have a look at my answer below:

The first sub could be written as:

```
Dim ExposureDataInput As Worksheet
Dim ManualSimulation As Worksheet

Set EDI = Sheets("ExposureDataInput")
Set MS = Sheets("ManualSimulation")

Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

    For i = 2 To EDI.Range("B" & EDI.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If EDI.Range("B" & i).Value > 0 Then
           n = MS.Cells(MS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
           'get the next free row without data on Column A
           MS.Range("A" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 1).Value
           MS.Range("B" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 2).Value
           MS.Range("C" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 4).Value
           MS.Range("D" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 6).Value
           MS.Range("E" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 8).Value
           MS.Range("F" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 10).Value
           MS.Range("G" & n).Value = EDI.Cells(i, 12).Value
        End If
    Next i
```

The second sub could be written as:

```
Dim ExposureDataInput As Worksheet
Dim HistoricalDataandExcessReturns As Worksheet

Set EDI = Sheets("ExposureDataInput")
Set HDaER = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns")

Dim k As Long
Dim y As Long

    For k = 1 To EDI.Cells(EDI.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        If EDI.Range("B" & k).Value > 0 Then
            y = HDaER.Cells(1, HDaER.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            'count the number of column on row 1
            HDaER.Cells(1, y).Value = EDI.Cells(k, 1).Value

            y = HDaER.Cells(2, HDaER.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            'count the number of columns on row 2?
            HDaER.Cells(2, y).Value = EDI.Cells(k, 2).Value
       End If
    Next k
```

Comment: @ Xabier, Let me see

Comment: @ Xabier, it gives me the same error, but on this line: `HDaER.Range(y & 1).Value = EDI.Cells(1, k).Value`

Comment: @I.Я.Newb updated my answer, the Range was incorrect, I replaced it with Cells

Comment: @ Xabier, Let's see.

Comment: @ Xabier, Now I don't get an error, but I don't get the values from EDI sheet to HDaER sheet. Nothing. Just blanks. And the Macro runs and completes the task.

Comment: Did you check your last columns Row 1 and 2, as `HDaER.Cells(2, y).Value = EDI.Cells(2, k).Value` implies that if EDI's value on Column B > 0 then write to last column... I'm not too sure what you are trying to do...

Comment: I am trying to get the values from col A:A in EDI in Row 1 in HDaER. cell bu cell until an empty cell is reached

Comment: @I.Я.Newb Updated my answer, please try again, I believe it should work as you expected now. :)

Comment: OK... Now I got it running, but it is pasting the values in sheet HDaER from col B:B on, not from cl A:A on. I suppose I can get `k` to run from from 3, instead of 2 to lastrow and just type the headers from row 2, but if it is possible to add the headers as well will be great

Comment: It should be passing values from Column A to Row 1 and from Column B to row 2, I've also updated my answer to copy the headers. Please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks :)

Comment: Of course! Don't think that I wont. I would just like to ask what were the general mistakes that I made on this, just to take them as a note.

Comment: I also gave you an UpVote, that will be recorded, but my Votes will not be shown until I get 15 pts of props. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @I.Я.Newb the main thing was `Range(y & 2)` that is not an acceptable range, so I amended that to `Cells(2, y)` which means row 2, column y. And  for `EDI.Cells(k, 2)` you had k and 2 the other way around...

Comment: I highly appreciate your effort! However, I can not get my head around the fact that it works just fine with `ì` for the row to row in the first part of the code.

Comment: @I.Я.Newb sometimes it is easy to make that mistake, as Range("A2"), you have A which is the column and 2 which is the row, whereas using Cells(2,1), 2 is the row and 1 is the column, so Range("A2") = Cells(2, 1)

Comment: That's because in the first part of your code you used Range("A" & i) which is acceptable if i is 2 then Range("A2") which is OK, but when you tried with your y value, you didn't specify a column..

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, your correction of the first part of the code made it run faster, so thumbs up for that one also.

Comment: I got my Voting rights back, here is your UpVote as a sure sign of appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the error you should be getting is `6` - Overflow.

Try this small piece of code:

```
Sub TestMe()        
    Dim a As Integer
    a = Rows.Count    
End Sub
```

You would get an overflow error, because the Integer is from `-32768` to `32767` and the rows in Excel are more than 1 million. The columns are `16384`, thus they enough for an `integer`.

Replace the `Integer` with `Long` and try again.

Comment: I was getting that error at one point and I replaced the `Ìnteger` w `Long`.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. Although, @ Xabier provided a solution to the issue, while improving the first part of the code, your answer was very thoughtful and rapid. Maybe it would have provided a solution to a different issue. However, if you have anything to add to the Question's Answers, or to the comments above, please feel free to do so, while the high value of your comments are surely to be rewarded the appropriate for Stack Overflow way. Thank you for the time and effort.